# On conflict, change insert values

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Given the schema

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `text` TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`name`)
)
```

I would like to insert new data in such a way that if a given name exists, the name I am trying to insert is changed. I've checked the SQLite docs, and all I could find is INSERT OR REPLACE, which would change the `text` of the existing `name` instead of creating a new element.

The only solution I can think of is

```
def merge_or_edit(curr, *data_tuples):
    SELECT = """SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `test` WHERE `name`=?"""
    INSERT = """INSERT INTO `test` (`name`, `text`) VALUES (?, ?)"""

    to_insert = []
    for t in data_tuples:
        while curr.execute(SELECT, (t[0],)).fetchone()[0] == 1:
            t = (t[0] + "_", t[1])
        to_insert.append(t)

    curr.executemany(INSERT, to_insert)
```

But this solution is extremely slow for large sets of data (and will crash if the rename takes its name to more than 255 chars.)
What I would like to know is if this functionality is even possible using raw SQLite code.

Comment: There is no faster mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I guess that at least since this code is only going to be run once, it's mostly fine that is slow.